# ASP Classic - How to count the number of sub items in a nested list

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a nested list that I use to display available videos from the db grouped under their respective headers.
I'm wondering if it's possible to count the number of videos in each grouping so that I could display it like this:

Video Group Title 1 (3 videos)
1. Video 1
2. Video 2
3. Video 3
Video Group Title 2 (6 videos)
1. Video 1
2. Video 2
...etc.

The SQL is pretty simple right now:

```
SELECT * FROM video_module_type;
```

I'm using ASP VBscript and the code for what I've got is:

```
<%
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'VARIABLES
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim previous_video_module_name
Dim first_video_module_name
Dim DIV_vms_vid_title
Dim DIV_vms_grouping
Dim DIV_video_section_group
Dim DIV_vms_video_holder
Dim DIV_vms_sm_thumb
Dim DIV_vms_results
Dim vms_shim
Dim DIV_end

previous_video_module_name = ""
first_video_module_name = true

DIV_vms_vid_title = "<div class=""vms_vid_title"">"
DIV_vms_grouping = "<div id=""sustvid_webinar"" class=""vms_grouping"">"
DIV_video_section_group = "<div class=""video_section_group"">"
DIV_vms_video_holder = "<div class=""vms_video_holder"">"
DIV_vms_sm_thumb = "<div class=""vms_sm_thumb"">"
DIV_vms_vid_synopsis = "<div class=""vms_vid_synopsis"">"
DIV_vms_results = "<div class=""vms_results"">"
vms_shim = "<img src=""/images/shim.gif"" width=""16"" height=""16"">"
DIV_end = "</div>"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'IF NOT THE SAME VALUE AS PREVIOUS
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for i = 0 to videoModulesListerNumber-1

    if video_module_name(i) <> previous_video_module_name then
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'IF NOT THE FIRST TIME, CLOSE THE NESTED LIST
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if first_video_module_name then
              response.Write("<h2>" & video_module_name(i) & "</h2>")
            end if
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'DISPLAY THE CATEGORY
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        response.Write("<!--START VIDEO GROUP: " & video_module_name(i) & "-->")
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'IF NOT THE SAME VALUE AS PREVIOUS OPEN THE NESTED LIST AND STORE THE CURRENT 
            'VALUE FOR COMPARISON NEXT TIME
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        previous_video_module_name = video_module_name(i)
    end if
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'DISPLAY THE VIDEOS 
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    response.Write(DIV_vms_grouping)
    response.Write(DIV_video_section_group)
    response.Write(DIV_vms_video_holder)
    response.Write(DIV_vms_vid_title & "<h2>" & video_module_video_name(i) & "</h2>" & DIV_end)
    response.Write(DIV_vms_sm_thumb & video_module_thumbnail(i) & DIV_end)
    response.Write(DIV_vms_vid_synopsis)
    response.Write("<p>" & video_module_synopsis(i) & "</p>")
    response.Write(DIV_vms_results & vms_shim & DIV_end)
    response.Write(DIV_end) ' close DIV_vms_grouping
    response.Write(DIV_end) ' close DIV_video_section_group
    response.Write(DIV_end) ' close DIV_vms_video_holder
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'IT'S NO LONGER THE FIRST TIME; CHANGE THE "first_video_module_name" VARIABLE
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    first_video_module_name = false
next

%>
```

I think the problem may be that I don't know what the term for this is, so I can't search for it, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, you would update your SQL query to include the video count in the result set, and just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query to something like

```
SELECT video_module_type.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                             FROM video_module_type as t2 
                             WHERE t2.Group = video_module_type.VideoGroup) as GroupCount 
FROM video_module_type
```

And use the `GroupCount` field.

**OR**

You can traverse the results two times, the first time counting the items and the second time displaying the results

**OR**

You can use Javascript to count the items and display the results
[->JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RVuxP/)

Comment: Just for my own education, what would you call what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Also, if there is another video group, will it be a single number that counts BOTH groups, or gives me the number of videos per separate group?

Comment: I'd call it Grouping. Some libraries (like SlickGrid) can do the count for you. http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

Comment: Has for the second question: Each record will have the GroupCount field (it's a little overhead for each record) with the number of videos on their own group. You will need to do the same `if video_module_name(i) <> previous_video_module_name then` but you will have the number of videos available

Comment: Check out the JsFiddle sample for the Javascript part